# Find out in c# if a class inherit from interface directly

Tags: c#, system.reflection, ef-core-2.0

i want to know if a class inherit directly from an interface or not. something like the `Type.IsSubClass` but for interface.

for

```
interface IOne{}
class Zero{}
class One:IOne{}
class Two:One{}
class Three: Zero, IOne{}

type(Three).IsSubInterface(IOne)  //should return true
type(Two).IsSubInterface(IOne)    //should return false
```

i tried to play with `Type.GetInterfaces` and Type.BaseType but couldnt' figure out the direct way to get if SubInterface is a class or not.
the `typeof(IOne).IsAssignableFrom` isn't working for me since it's checking the whole tree of inheritance, but here I just want to check if a class directly inherit from an interface or not.

the reason behind is in efcore to audit only those entity that inherits from `IAudit` interface not any entity that inherits from the audited entity.

the other solution rather than `IAudit` i thought was to create an attribute, but my life will be much easier if i can solve this with an interface

Comment: I seem to recall that this information is not readily available, you also have a different type that you need to decide on: `class TwoPlus:One, IOne{}`

Comment: thanks but i have some class that already are inheriting from other classes, this way i can't add audit for them

Comment: My point is this: If you have a base class implementing the interface you're saying you want to audit this class, but any class that derives from the base class, you don't want to audit them. Well, can't you simply detect that the parent class implements the same interface and that is your signal?

Comment: Small caveat: classes don't "inherit from an interface" they *implement* an interface. -- In your example, `Two` still *implements* the interface `IOne` albeit "indirectly" via `One`. -- Not sure if this distinction is available.

Comment: Seems like a very *brittle* type design if you need to distinguish types in this manner. Are you sure you're modelling things correctly?

Comment: What's the point of having an _audited entity_ (presumably which implements `IAudit`) if you don't want to act on all of them ? Your design looks _flaky_ and you should consider rework it instead of trying to hack around with reflection.

Comment: it's just for better control; if someone comes and mistakenly add `IAudit` to a base interface cause the whole db go crazy with auditing. the audit is an expensive task since I'm doing extra read for capture old state and insert new record along old record.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, efcore now support [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance), let say i have `GeneralNotes` and `ManagerNotes` and `SecurityNotes`. all of the notes have same structure. so manager and `SecurityNote` inherit from the `GeneralNote`. but i want audit only on `SecurityNotes` not the two others, it's normal structure, this structure still it's fine, since manager and security is later addon to the project. add a new base class for everything is not feasible

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    interface IOne { }
    class Zero { }
    class One : IOne { }
    class Two : One { }
    class Three : Zero, IOne { }

    public static class TypeExt
    {
        public static bool IsSubInterface(this Type t1, Type t2)
        {
            if (!t2.IsAssignableFrom(t1))
                return false;

            if (t1.BaseType == null)
                return true;

            return !t2.IsAssignableFrom(t1.BaseType);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Three).IsSubInterface(typeof(IOne)));
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Two).IsSubInterface(typeof(IOne)));
        }
    }
}
```

If the type does not implement `t2` then the answer is always `false`.

If the type has no base class but implements `t2` then it must be the implementing class, so the answer is true.

If the type implements `t2`, has a base class, and that base class doesn't implement `t2` then the answer is `true`.

Otherwise the answer is false.

This might not work for all cases; the question is: Does it work for the cases that you want it to work for?

HOWEVER: I'm not sure this is a design route that you want to go down. It seems a bit hacky. I agree with /u/Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment above.

Comment: Not sure it can detect re-implementation of an interface... Like [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABADAAmwEYBuAWAChsBmfASwDt4EAzCAYznwElunE2nSgG9KAX0qUahAEz4AQtC4gefZoK4jxkqrWxyAygFdg+FYqhwkq/qw6aKoimKA===)

Comment: But I'm not even sure if it is possible to do it... It seems that that information (while present in the compiled assembly) is hidden by the .NET